# Elasticsearch substring matchng without ending

Tags: elasticsearch

For example if my search word is: "`Houses`" I want found result "`House`" how to search without last 1-2 word letters ?

I try "`nGram`" filter, but it serrch for full word.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are chasing the wrong approach.
Judging by your example , i feel what you are looking is stemmers.
Elasticsearch has stemmers like snowball which can convert any word to their base forms or stems.

For eg: , the stemmer can convert

```
[ "jumping" , "jumped" ] -> "jump"
[ "staying" , "stayed" ] -> "stay"
```

And so on...

Snowball - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html#analysis-snowball-analyzer